# load foreign characters from xml file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, xml

Am loading an XML file but at the same time there are some Greek characters inside the file like "ναι" and when I load them on a data grid view table they appear like ���.

Am using xmlreader to load it with the encoding iso-8859-7 like

```
public XmlDocument LoadDocument(String x)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(x, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")))
    {
        document.Load(stream);

    }
    return (document);
}
```

Comment: Check that your document is actually encoded in iso-8859-7 and not in somehthing different (e.g. UTF-8)

Comment: the encoding is UTF-8

Comment: If the encoding is UTF-8, you shouldn't try to load it in a different encoding. That's like trying to open a PNG as a JPEG and expecting something useful to come out...

Comment: it doesnt make a difference in which encoding i load it .it still doesnt show the chars

Comment: what do you mean "show" where?

Comment: data grid view table or anywhere else i need them

Comment: The first thing you need to do is work out whether the XML itself is broken or not. What happens if you open it in a browser? What has produced it?

Comment: it doesn't mean it didn't read them correctly. can you give us the numerical values of the charterers in the file and in the debugger? and also a snippet of the beginning of the file, and the relevant part that fails to read?

Comment: these are the values ��� from the debugger

Comment: No. the numerical values as in: 0x32 0x4e etc...

Comment: no numerical vals. vals come from a nodelist like XmlNodeList properties = commonMethods.LoadDocument(xml).DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + curClass + "']/Property[@Entity='" + curEntity + "']");

Comment: please read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and come back to us....

Comment: I guess that what you did is took a file, said in your mind that it's UTF-8 but actually wrote some iso-8859-7 or UTF-16 (.Net's default encoding) inside it...

Comment: nope the file encoding is UTF-8 but it has iso-8859-7 characters

Comment: basically i want to change the encoding to iso-8859 on the runtime to be able to read those chars and then change it back again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59512/discussion-between-angelos-cle-and-ak).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer here is not to use `StreamReader` at all. Let the XML parser handle the encoding appropriately:

```
public XmlDocument LoadDocument(String x)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(x))
    {
        document.Load(stream);

    }
    return document;
}
```

Or just use [`XmlDocument.Load(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public XmlDocument LoadDocument(String x)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(x);
    return document;
}
```

The XML document should specify its encoding in the XML declaration if it needs to - and *that's* the best source of truth.

Comment: this way is not working .thats why am migrating to the option of stream reader because of those characters. the file encoding is UTF-8

Comment: @angelos_cle: If the file encoding is UTF-8 then why would you try to load it in ISO-8859-7? Are you saying your XML file is basically broken? If so, you should have made that clear in the question - I would perform a "fixing" operation separately, personally.

Comment: @JonSkeet Im guessing its utf8 but without the BOM or the XML encoding thingy so the XmlDocument treats it as ansi...

Comment: @AK_: No, XmlDocument will follow the XML specification, which says that if there's no declaration it *must* be in UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: @AK_: This is more a matter of knowing the XML spec than .NET... it would be a pretty broken XML parser that assumed an ANSI encoding when the XML specification says otherwise.